# Save current page/image and modify/view it again in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm doing my work on Google Map, after I have planted some markers on Google Map, is there anyway that I can 'save' my current Google Map and maybe modify/view it again on a later date/time? Any function or anything?

No idea at all. Thanks!

Comment: Cookies are good enough IMO.. just store as little data as possible since cookie storage is very limited (around 2K only). For example you can store it like this: `[110x90,350x11]` then parse this as array of the marker coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localStorage() or sessionStorage() is awesome to save and retrieve JS (and/or any other data) client side

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you use html and javascript on the client.
If you want to save a client's job you must do somekind of serverside work.
Maybe save in a database or for a project that is only visible to you, you can save in a xml file.
However all these functions must take place in the server as javascript is client side scripting not allowing disk operations.

And the last that i can think of is to use cookies for temporary storage.

Comment: Yah... I can only think of storing them using cookies. Thanks man!

Comment: You are welcome.You can vote up any answers are helpful.Also answers appear in backwards order meaning the first answer will appear last.Cheers